# Mercurial: how to show branches in autocompletion

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, mercurial

It is possible to update to a specific tag or branch with the `hg update <branch-or-tag>` command. However, the built-in completion only shows me tags (not branches). So when i type `hg update` and hit tab, i get a list of tags, but no branches. Is it possible to add branches to this list?

Or may this even be a bug in Mercurial?

I am using zsh and oh-my-zsh with Mercurial installed via Homebrew.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current code of `_hg` (Zsh 5.0.2) only completes with tags:

a brief look at the source of `_hg` (the completion function for mercurial) shows that the completion for `hq update` (implemented by the function `_hg_cmd_update` really only returns revisions and tags:

```
_hg_cmd_update() {
  _arguments -s -w : $_hg_global_opts \
  '(--clean -C)'{-C,--clean}'[overwrite locally modified files]' \
  '(--rev -r)'{-r+,--rev}'[revision]:revision:_hg_tags' \
  ':revision:_hg_tags'
}
```

Location: I think the easiest thing would be to call `locate _hq`, but normally I would expect the function to be at `/usr/share/zsh/5.0.2/functions`. The exact sub-folder may change due to installation options. Safest thing is to download the 5.0.2 tar ball, and look at `zsh-5.0.2/Completion/Unix/Command/_hg`

Comment: Where do i find the zsh completion function so i can patch it? I could only find bash completion...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 16.04 default `zsh 5.1.1`.

To get around it I just manually patched `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_hg`

Replacing the `_hg_tags()` function with

```
_hg_tags() {
  local expl
  typeset -a hglabels
  hglabels=( ${(f)"$(_hg_cmd debugnamecomplete -q 2>/dev/null)"} )
  _wanted labels expl 'labels' compadd -a - hglabels
}
```

edit: Worth mentioning I'm using `Mercurial (version 3.7.3)` as `debugnamecomplete` isn't on all versions of mercurial. You can easily test if the version you are using supports it by type `hg debugnamecomplete`. If not supported just update mercurial as well.

Comment: This solved it from me. Will this change revert back after zsh updates?

Comment: I suspect it would get overwritten. An alternative to avoid zsh updates clobbering it would be to install `oh-my-zsh` and instead of modifying `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_hg` just copy it to `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/hg/_hg` then modify it. After that modify `~/.zshrc` to load the custom zsh plugin `plugins=(... hg)`.

I've actually had to do this for OSX because `/usr/share` has additional security to prevent modifications to System files.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue `hg up` branches autocomplete by rewriting the _hg_tags() function with the following:

```
_hg_tags() {
  typeset -a tags
  local tag rev

  _hg_cmd tags 2> /dev/null | while read tag
  do
    tags+=(${tag/ #    [0-9]#:*})
  done
  _hg_cmd branches 2> /dev/null | while read tag
  do
    tags+=(${tag/ #    [0-9]#:*})
  done
  (( $#tags )) && _describe -t tags 'tags' tags
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The version of the tab completion script for mercurial that ships with zsh is a bit out of date (doesn't support bookmarks or branches).  There is a more up to date version in the mercurial source.  homebrew doesn't seem to install this script so I found the best thing is to download the mercurial source and add the zsh_completion script to the zsh fpath.